# WSAEventSelect() makes a socket descriptor no longer a socket

Tags: winsock

I am writing a cross-platform socket handling library (which also handles serial and a whole bunch of other protocols in a protocol agnostic way. - I am not re-inventing the wheel).

I need to emulate the Linux poll function. The code I started with used select and worked fine, but there was no way to interrupt it from another thread, and so I was *forced* to start using event objects. My initial attempt called:

```
WSACreateEvent()
WSAEventSelect() to associate the socket with the event object.
WaitForMultipleObjectsEx() to wait on all sockets plus my interrupt event object.
select() to work out what events actually occurred on the socket.
accept()/send()/recv() to process the sockets (later and elsewhere).
```

This failed. `accept()` was claiming that the file descriptor was not a socket. If I commented out the call to `WSAEventSelect()`, essentially reverting to my earlier code, it all works fine (except that I cannot interrupt).

I then realised that I did something *wrong* (according to the Microsoft dictatorship). Instead of using `select()` to work out what events have happened on each socket, I should be using `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`. So I rewrote my code to do it the proper way, remembering to call `WSAEventSelect()` afterwards to disassociate the event object from the file descriptor so that (fingers crossed) `accept()` would now work.

Now `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` is returning an error and `WSAGetLastError()` tells me that the error is `WSAENOTSOCK`.

This IS a socket. I am doing things the way MSDN tells me I should (allowing for the general poor quality of the documentation). It appears however that `WSAEventSelect()` is causing the file descriptor to be marked as a file rather than a socket.

I hate Microsoft so much right now.

Here is a cut down version of my code:

```
bool do_poll(std::vector<struct pollfd> &poll_data, int timeout)
{
    ...
    for (const auto &fd_data : poll_data) {
        event_mask = 0;
        if (0 != (fd_data.events & POLLIN)) {
            // select() will mark a socket as readable when it closes (read size = 0) or (for
            // a listen socket) when there is an incoming connection. This is the *nix paradigm.
            // WSAEventSelect() hasseparate events.
            event_mask |= FD_READ;
            event_mask |= FD_ACCEPT;
            event_mask |= FD_CLOSE;
        }
        if (0 != (fd_data.events & POLLOUT)) {
            event_mask |= FD_WRITE;
        }
        event_obj = WSACreateEvent();
        events.push_back(event_obj);
        if (WSA_INVALID_EVENT != event_obj) {
            (void)WSAEventSelect((SOCKET)fd_data.fd, event_obj, event_mask);
        }
    }

    lock.lock();

    if (WSA_INVALID_EVENT == interrupt_obj) {
        interrupt_obj = WSACreateEvent();
    }

    if (WSA_INVALID_EVENT != interrupt_obj) {
        events.push_back(interrupt_obj);
    }

    lock.unlock();

    ...

    (void)WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(events.size(), &(events[0]), FALSE, dw_timeout, TRUE);

    for (i = 0u; i < poll_data.size(); i++) {
        if (WSA_INVALID_EVENT == events[i]) {
            poll_data[i].revents |= POLLERR;
        } else {
            if (0 != WSAEnumNetworkEvents((SOCKET)(poll_data[i].fd), events[i], &revents)) {
                poll_data[i].revents |= POLLERR;
            } else {
                if (0u != (revents.lNetworkEvents & (FD_READ | FD_ACCEPT | FD_CLOSE))) {
                    poll_data[i].revents |= POLLIN;
                }

                if (0u != (revents.lNetworkEvents & FD_WRITE)) {
                    poll_data[i].revents |= POLLOUT;
                }
            }

            (void)WSAEventSelect((SOCKET)(poll_data[i].fd), NULL, 0);
            (void)WSACloseEvent(event_obj);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Calling `WSAEventSelect((SOCKET)fd, NULL, 0)` after calling `select()` in the code I started with works! Hurrah! However, since `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` needs the event object, and presumably needs it still associated with the socket, this doesn't solve my problem.It *appears* from the MSDN documentation that you should have the event object associated for the lifetime of the socket, and moreover calling `WSAEventSelect()` a second time for the same socket clears the internal network event log.

Comment: ()` is fundamentally borked. My "solution" is to go with my first option, but call `WSAEventSelect()` with a NULL pointer after calling `select()`. This is a nasty heap of steaming Microsoft product, but it works.

Comment: I don't know why `select()` works without calling `WSAEventSelect()` while `accept()` and friends do not. I would like to know why. I would also be interested in a working example using `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`. I cannot believe even the incompetents at Microsoft could release an API that completely and utterly fails to work in all situations. Maybe it is just completely incorrect documentation that has me stumped.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis/pull/422#issuecomment-716407328